# Does projection in ArcGIS Desktop matter if my goal is to publish it in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: projection, map-projections

I have a couple layers in a map in ArcGIS Desktop. I will publish this in my ArcGIS Online account. Does it matter making all the projections of the layers the same in Desktop when my goal is to then publish it in ArcGIS Online (which uses Web Mercator Auxiliary projection)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the data with an Esri basemap, you can publish layers in whatever source projection you want. It will project everything to match the basemap (Web Mercator Auxiliary) [on the fly](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/73058/how-does-arcgis-determine-which-transformation-to-use-when-projecting-on-the-fly).

It is possible to publish your own basemap and therefore use whatever projection you want (ref. [Esri blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/12/16/using-your-own-basemaps/)), but most people don't have their own tiled basemap scheme.

While it isn't *necessary* to put everything into the same coordinate system within ArcMap, it is often good practice to have a consistent projection for your source data or at the very least to know what your projection was before publishing. So consider doing it anyways :)